# Can I somehow not write out the full qualified return type name?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, clang, code-duplication

I have the following case of a nested class:

```
class PS_OcTree {
public:
  // stuff ...

private:
  struct subdiv_criteria : public octree_type::subdiv_criteria {
    PS_OcTree* tree;
    subdiv_criteria(PS_OcTree* _tree) : tree(_tree) { }
    virtual Element elementInfo(unsigned int const& elem, node const* n) override;
  };
};
```

To implement this method in the `.cpp` file, I write

```
PS_OcTree::subdiv_criteria::Element
PS_OcTree::subdiv_criteria::elementInfo(
  unsigned int const& poly_index, node const* n)
{
    // implementation goes here
}
```

I'm fine with writing the full name of the method, but do I really also need to write the full name of the return type? Inside the parameter parentheses and the function body, I can access names of the `subdiv_criteria` class, but that doesn't seem to work for the return type.

Preferrably, I'd like to write something like

```
Element PS_OcTree::subdiv_criteria::elementInfo(
  unsigned int const& poly_index, node const* n)
{
    // implementation goes here
}

// or

auto PS_OcTree::subdiv_criteria::elementInfo(
  unsigned int const& poly_index, node const* n)
{
    // implementation goes here
}
```

At least something that doesn't require me to repeat `PS_OcTree::subdiv_criteria` in the return type. Is there something in C++11 that I can use? It should work with MSVC 2015 and Clang 5 as well.

Comment: In C++11 you can write `auto PS_OcTree::subdiv_criteria::elementInfo(
  unsigned int const& poly_index, node const* n) -> Element` .   IDK if MSVC supports this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class-scope lookup applies to anything after the *declarator-id* (which is the name of the function being defined, i.e., `PS_OcTree::subdiv_criteria::elementInfo`), including a trailing return type. Hence,

```
auto PS_OcTree::subdiv_criteria::elementInfo(
  unsigned int const& poly_index, node const* n) -> Element 
{
}
```

Comment: Slick! Thanks, I didn't figure this out. :)